# Resources for image processing/analysis with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, automation, data-analysis, defects

I have minor Python experience. I would like to change that with the help of whatever suggestions you may have for me.

I would like to create a program which could process several images one-by-one and output edited images where all particles in the original image have been detected and classified; this could also be supplemented by additional spreadsheet data which lists the total amount of particles, their size categories, and other parameters specific to each detected particle. Example: Black circles or ellipses over a gray background are detected and the results are output; there are 3 circles, 4 ellipses, etc.

I would like to learn how to write such a program, or series of scripts, by myself, or at least have a better idea of how to proceed. I am most familiar with Python. Could anyone with particle detection/analysis, image processing experience please direct me toward material that would be helpful in my case? It can be something as basic as Python for Dummies, just anything someone in the field has once read and would consider conducive to my end goal. Anything that could provide me with bits of knowledge necessary to make the above idea a reality. Any books, videos, websites, regardless of skill level necessary, advanced or basic, would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking about two things:

1. Image recognition
2. Image analysis

For the first, it's a fairly wide topic. Depending on your use case, scikit-learn might cover your needs. The scikit-learn assumes some knowledge about ML / image recognition though. It's showing **how to use their tools** to do what you know you want to do. So, if you know aobut image recognition already, then scikit-learn is a good place to go next.

Good examples include

- classifying the classic MNIST hand-written digits dataset: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html
- face detection: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html

Regarding image analysis, commonly used libraries include OpenCV. I'd point in your the direction of their free courses:

https://opencv.org/university/free-courses/

Good luck!